# Occasional "Failed to Fetch" on file upload

Tags: amazon-s3, file-upload, fetch-api

I've been having a really hard time tracking down a bug that occasionally shows up in production, and I'm hoping someone has run across something similar or has some insight.

I was initially made aware of the error through Sentry, which was reporting an abnormal number of "Apollo: Failed to Fetch" errors (I use apollo with graphql). After some investigation I narrowed this down to calls that included file uploads (I use [apollo-upload-client](https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client) to create multipart uploads for files. Thinking that it may be an issue with the library, I replaced one of my file upload implementations with a direct upload to S3 using presigned urls. Unfortunately that didn't solve the issue, and I continued to get a percentage of users running into file upload problems.

I then found [this discussion](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/5334) and [this one](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/issues/1464) which indicated that it might have something to do with the `keepalive` flag on fetch. That tracks to some extent, because all of my errors for the issue are reported from chrome and safari. But my file uploads are in the realm of 20kb - 100kb, which is under the limit mentioned in one of those posts. Directly setting `keepalive` false has no effect.

Finally, I installed the `unfetch` polyfill library, and forced usage of that instead of native `fetch` (`unfetch` doesn't support `keepalive`). This kind of worked - I no longer am seeing the "Failed to Fetch" errors, but I now see some additional errors that I suspect are a result of the limited feature set of `unfetch`. I would also like to not have to rely on this hack if possible. Any ideas on what the problem could be?

Additional notes:

- This is the code for the fetch call:

```js
const response = await (pFetch as Unfetch)(url, {
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': file.type,
  },
  body: file
});
```

- I don't think it's a CORS issue - my S3 bucket has my domain in the CORS allowlist
- My backend is Ruby on Rails, but that shouldn't make a difference since I get the error on direct upload to S3 as well
- Sentry replays don't show anything showing up in the dev console

Comment: Given that you mentioned it happens to some users and not others, are you validating the allowed file types for storage/upload? A longshot guess is that people are uploading a unsupported file type, and when you then the img.src URL isn't supporting an image type.

Comment: Ya for the direct upload through my server I validate the file extension on the frontend, and then validate that the extension matches the mime type on the server. On the direct upload to S3 I can't do that but I've tested changing the extension for a mime type and still can't reproduce